# Regarding print a pattern

Tags: loops, c++11

**Question**
How can I give spaces between numbers? When I add a `<<" "` after `cout<<j` the pattern changed. Is there any other way to give spaces between numbers?

**code**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int i,j=1,space,star,n;
cin>>n;
i=1;
```

**Looping**

```
while(i<=n){
space=n-i;
 while(space){
    cout<<" ";
    space--;
 }
star=i;
while(star){
cout<<j<<" ";
j++;
star--;
}
cout<<"\n";
   i++;
}
return 0;

}
```

**output**
for n=4

```
    1
   23
  456
 78910
```

I want this output :-

```
      1
    2 3
  3 4 5
7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the expected output you only need to add a second space in the `while(space)` loop:

```
    space = n - i;
    while (space) {
        std::cout << "  "; // note: two spaces
        space--;
    }
```

or multiply `space` by `2` before the loop:

```
    space = 2 * (n - i);
    while (space) {
        std::cout << ' ';
        space--;
    }
```

You could also `#include <string>` and skip the loop:

```
    space = 2 * (n - i);
    std::cout << std::string(space, ' ');
```

Another way of skipping the loop is to `#include <iomanip>` and use [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

Note that you can use `std::setw` and [`std::left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) to correct the `while (star)` loop too to make this pattern hold for up to `n = 13`.

```
    space = 2 * (n - i) + 1;
    std::cout << std::setw(space) << "";

    while (star) {
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::left << j;
        j++;
        star--;
    }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/avbxjKToW)

Comment: why cout<<j<<"\n" not working

Comment: @xaviour1504 That will make it jump to a new line after each printed `j` and will surely destroy the pattern.

Comment: sorry, I want to ask you why cout<<j<<" " ; is not working.

Comment: @xaviour1504 a one digit number + a space makes two characters, so you need two spaces to indent the blank part of each line.